# How can I concat two arrays of objects in a tree structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays of objects
The first array

```
    [
      { 
        value: 'Node 1',
        id: 1,
        childs: [
          {
            value: 'Node 2',
            id : 2,
            childs: [
              {
                value: 'Node 3',
                id: 3
              },
              {
                value: 'Node 4',
                id: 4           
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

and the second array

```
    [
      { 
        value: 'Node 1',
        id: 1,
        childs: [
          {
            value: 'Node 5',
            id : 5
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

and i don't understand how can i concat these arrays of object in a tree structure.
I need this result

```
    [
      { 
        value: 'Node 1',
        id: 1,
        childs: [
          {
            value: 'Node 2',
            id : 2,
            childs: [
              {
                value: 'Node 3',
                id: 3
              },
              {
                value: 'Node 4',
                id: 4           
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            value: 'Node 5',
            id : 5
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

and these arrays can be more difficult and have more childs.

How can i get what i want?

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see why is this an AngularJS question.

Comment: yea sorry, i do it in angularjs, but it's just JS

Comment: @Farsay probably as he put only what he want to get but his code he tried till now

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Array#forEach` function and `Array#filter`

```js
var arr = [ { value: 'Node 1', id: 1, childs: [ { value: 'Node 2', id : 2, childs: [ { value: 'Node 3', id: 3 }, { value: 'Node 4', id: 4 
} ] } ] } ];
var arr2= [ { value: 'Node 1', id: 1, childs: [ { value: 'Node 5', id : 5 } ] } ]

arr.forEach(function(a){
    var k =arr2.filter(i=> a.value == i.value);
    a.childs.push(...k[0].childs)
  })
  
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: it's close, but if i change the second array and add child for node 2
and i will have node 1-> node 2-> node 4
i will get two elements node 2. 
for example https://jsfiddle.net/LLqvnesa/

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach by hashing the id for the actual level.

```js
function update(target, source) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    target.forEach(function (o) {
        hash[o.id] = o;
    });
    source.forEach(function (o, i, a) {
        if (hash[o.id]) {
            o.children && update(hash[o.id].children = hash[o.id].children || [], o.children)
        } else {
            target.push(o);
        }
    });
}
var array1 = [{ value: 'Node 1', id: 1, children: [{ value: 'Node 2', id: 2, children: [{ value: 'Node 3', id: 3 }, { value: 'Node 4', id: 4 }] }] }],
    array2 = [{ value: 'Node 1', id: 1, children: [{ value: 'Node 5', id: 5 }] }];

update(array1, array2);

console.log(array1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `concat()` method. [See this.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_concat_array.asp)
So your code should look like this:

```
array1[0].children.concat(array2[0].children);
```